# how to execute a file from some deep directory?

Tags: linux, find

Guys i want to execute a file, knowing only its filename but i dont know its exact location inside my home directory so i think im gonna use `find` to find it but i dont know the next step in executing it. And my file is in type `perl`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
find /dir -name "filename" -exec {} \;
```

Would also be good to check that the file is executable...

```
find /dir -name "filename" -perm /u+x -exec {} \;
```

Comment: This is better than mine for if the file is executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find /your/home/dir -name "filename.pl" | xargs perl
```

This will locate the file then execute it.  Of course, you could simply run `find` then type

```
perl /path/to/file/found/using/find/filename.pl
```

If you don't want to type the full path you could copy-paste the `fild` result.

Comment: how about if the file is just an executable file not a perl file?

Comment: But your post said it was a perl file... If it's executable you can call it like `/path/to/filename`.  I'm not sure how to do that in conjunction with `find`.

Comment: You can pass it to a small script to run it with `exec`.  For example, `find /path -options -exec sh -c 'exec {}' \;`